# How would I use a downloaded string for user input?

Tags: c#

I’m pretty new to C# and would like to learn how to use downloaded string from a url for user input, I know this has something to do with String.Contains, but I’m not entirely sure how to use it. The code below is how I believe you download string. If I’m doing anything wrong, please don’t hesitate to tell me.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
var response = wb.DownloadString("url");
}
```

Comment: Hi StepBro, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your it will be easy to understand

Comment: Well, that's how you'd use [WebClient.DownloadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netcore-3.1) but what are you doing with the user's input?

Comment: What do you mean by "use a downloaded string for user input"? Also, `string.Contains` is a method that just returns true if some text was present in a string and false if not.

Comment: For example, if the user inputs the downloaded string, x will happen

Comment: Another example would be; if I put “a” in a raw github link and the user inputted “a” x would happen

Comment: So you are writing a console application and you want to read input from the user? And check that input against the downloaded string?